# How do I view the transaction list for my debit card on Apple Pay?

Tags: iphone, apple-pay

I just got the iPhone 6 and I started using Apple Pay. I added my Bank of America debit card and an American Express credit card. Now whenever I use my Amex one, I get a notification as soon as I use it, and my last transaction is showing with the amount and the location, and I could also open a list to show the most recent transactions. My debit card doesn't do that at all. No notifications, no dollar amount, just says "Dallas, TX --" and doesn't put the dollar amount. I went into settings and into my BofA card and there's not even a "Card Notifications" slider so I can turn it on. Is there any way to bypass or fix this?

Answer (score 1):

BoA does have the mobile banking app.

> Mobile Banking Alerts
>
> Stay on top of your accounts
>
> AlertsFootnote 1 are customizable and can keep you informed of just
>   about everything that happens with your account. Stay in the know
>   about direct deposits, personal information changes, bill due dates
>   and more. Even find out when your account balance gets low so you can
>   make a deposit to help avoid overdraft charges and other fees.
>
> Information Icon Alerts are available exclusively in our iPhone, iPad
>   and Android Apps.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible on iOS 9 by using the Wallet app to inspect the card in question for banks that support the history being saved.

Tap the ⓘ and then look at the TRANSACTIONS section that's under the Card Notifications toggle.

For transactions that are from other Apple Pay devices (watch perhaps) and for transactions older than is displayed, you'll need to use your bank's mobile app, mobile web site or other account history / statements to retrieve those transactions. Worst case, you would reach out to your bank to see if/when they will support this feature on iOS.